# I want to get user values form database if they have

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table for the users and one table for order data. In my order table, I have lots of order data from various users so when I go to show them to his respective users I totally failed.

Actually, my main motive is to show the order data to my customers if they ordered otherwise they won't able to show the order data.
so how if, else condition should I use for this issue?
I want this code show if the user already place his order otherwise not..

```
<div class="order_data">
  <div class="single_order">

    <?php 
      while($order_res=mysqli_fetch_array($order_query)){
    ?>
        <a href="order.php">
            <div class="order_link">
                <i class="fa fa-bullseye" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <?php echo $order_res['order_title']?>
            </div>
        </a>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Check for a return, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php.

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).